# Get products by product tags

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, products, meta-tags

I'm trying to write my own search engine on my project. I'm trying to get products by product tags. How can I do that?

Edit: Actually, is magento search working by product tags or just product name and description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the tag 'sometag'.
You can get the product collection like this:

```
$tagname = 'sometag';
$tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($tagname);
//to get the product ids do this:
$ids = $tag->getRelatedProductIds(); //this will get you all the related product ids, even disabled

//to get the actual products do this:
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add default attributes to collection, You can use '*' for all
                ->addTagFilter($tag->getId()) //filter by the tag object
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) // filter by current store view since a product may be related to a tag only in some stores
                ->addMinimalPrice() //add the prices to the collection
                ->addUrlRewrite() //add url keys if needed
                ->setActiveFilter(); //some relations between tags and products may be disabled
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($products); //select only active products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($products); //get only visible products
```

And to answer you second question: NO, the search works only by product attributes that you set to be used in quick or advanced search.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I dont get it. The search working by product tags?

Comment: The search is not working by tags. you can only view products tagged with a specific tag in the tag's page. The search is done only on the product attributes. You can set the searchable product attribute in the backend by editing  any attribute and setting the flag 'Use for quick search' to yes or no.